# How to migrate Fusion Tables SQL API with New API in Java

Tags: java, google-fusion-tables

I am using Fusion Table SQL API in Java language and Application is hosted in Google App engine.
Application is adding and deleting record from fusion table by Java language.
But 
The Fusion Tables SQL API has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012 and will be shut down on December 26, 2012. 
So, I have to migrate Fusion Tables SQL API with New API.

My question is How to migrate Fusion Tables SQL API with New API in Java?

My current script is

```
import com.google.gdata.client.ClientLoginAccountType;
    import com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService;
    import com.google.gdata.client.Service.GDataRequest;
    import com.google.gdata.client.Service.GDataRequest.RequestType;

    import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
    import com.google.gdata.util.ContentType;
    import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLEncoder;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    public class SampleProgram {

      private static final String SERVICE_URL = "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query";

      private static final Pattern CSV_VALUE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([^,\\r\\n\"]*|\"(([^\"]*\"\")*[^\"]*)\")(,|\\r?\\n)");

      private GoogleService service;


      public SampleProgram(String email, String password) throws AuthenticationException 
      {
        service = new GoogleService("fusiontables", "fusiontables.ApiExample");
        service.setUserCredentials(email, password, ClientLoginAccountType.GOOGLE);
      }

      public String GetrunSelectQuery(String selectQuery) throws IOException,ServiceException 
      {
          URL url = new URL(SERVICE_URL + "?sql=" + URLEncoder.encode(selectQuery, "UTF-8"));
            GDataRequest request = service.getRequestFactory().getRequest(RequestType.QUERY, url, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

            request.execute();
            String decoded="";
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(request.getResponseStream(),"UTF-8");
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
              scanner.findWithinHorizon(CSV_VALUE_PATTERN, 0);
              MatchResult match = scanner.match();

              String quotedString = match.group(2);
              decoded = quotedString == null ? match.group(1): quotedString.replaceAll("\"\"", "\"");

            }
            return decoded;
      }



      public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, IOException 
      {

        String tableEncryptedID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        String sEmailId="XXXX@XXXXX.com";
        String sPassword="XXXXXXXXX";
        SampleProgram obj = new SampleProgram(sEmailId, sPassword);

        System.out.println(obj.GetrunSelectQuery("select name from "+tableEncryptedID+" limit 1"));

      }
    }
```